# Incorrect number of arguments for FUNCTION credit; expected 2, got 1

Tags: mysql

I had to create a function for "function to credit the amount to a particular account"

```
delimiter // 

create function `credit`(an VARCHAR(5), amt INT) 
RETURNS INT 
READS SQL DATA 

BEGIN
DECLARE bal INT;
SELECT balance INTO bal FROM ACCOUNT WHERE accno=an;
SET bal = bal + amt ;
UPDATE ACCOUNT SET balance = bal WHERE accno = an;
RETURN bal;
end //

DELIMITER ;
```

and when I try to call it out, I use:

```
SELECT accno,credit(balance)
FROM credit1
ORDER BY balance;
```

and here this is the error I get

> Incorrect number of arguments for FUNCTION credit; expected 2, got 1

Comment: It's defined as taking 2 arguments, so call it with 2. Error is abundantly clear, as is your function definition. Have you tried calling it with an `amt` arg?

Comment: MySQL function does not have optional parameters or default values for them. If your fn definition have 2 parameters (`an` and `amt`) then you must provide 2 parameters. One parameter or empty space instead of parameter not allowed.